# Parallel image renaming in Java with ExecutorService: Doesn't use 100% of my cpu-power

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, executor

I have a problem with my parallel Java-code. I try to read some images from the disk, change the names of the images and then save them again into a different folder.
To do so, I tried to run it in parallel as follows:

```
    int nrOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    int nrOfImagesPerThread = Math.round(remainingImages.size()/((float)nrOfThreads));

    ExecutorService ex2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nrOfThreads);
    int indexCounter = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i<  nrOfThreads; ++i) {
        if(i != (nrOfThreads-1)) {
            ex2.execute(new ImageProcessing(remainingImages.subList(indexCounter, indexCounter+nrOfImagesPerThread), newNames.subList(indexCounter,indexCounter+nrOfImagesPerThread))); 
            indexCounter+=nrOfImagesPerThread;
        }else {
            ex2.execute(new ImageProcessing(remainingImages.subList(indexCounter, remainingImages.size()), newNames.subList(indexCounter,remainingImages.size()))); 
        } 
    }


    ex2.shutdown();

    try {
        ex2.awaitTermination(12, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here is the ImageProcessing-class:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageProcessing implements Runnable {

private List<String> oldPaths;
private List<String> newPaths;

public ImageProcessing(List<String> oldPaths, List<String> newPaths) {
    this.oldPaths = oldPaths;
    this.newPaths = newPaths;
}

@Override
public void run() { 
    for(int i = 0; i<  oldPaths.size();++i) {
        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(oldPaths.get(i)));
            File output = new File(newPaths.get(i)); 
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", output);
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

I divide the image-locations in the for-loop into (number of threads)-parts, so in my case around 8 parts. When I now run the code, it does run in parallel, but it does not utilize 100% of my cpu power. It's only using around 25% of each processor.

Does anybody have an idea why that happend? Or did I just screw up somewhere in the programming?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**: Just for completion for people looking for the same functionality, I had a look at the Apache commons library ([see here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io//)) and found a nice and much faster way to copy the images from one HDD to the other. The ImageProcessing-class looks now like the following:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


public class ImageProcessing implements Runnable {

private List<String> oldPaths;
private List<String> newPaths;

public ImageProcessing(List<String> oldPaths, List<String> newPaths) {
    this.oldPaths = oldPaths;
    this.newPaths = newPaths;
}

@Override
public void run() { 
    for(int i = 0; i<  oldPaths.size();++i) {
        File sourceFile = new File(oldPaths.get(i)); 

        File targetFile = new File(newPaths.get(i)); 
        //copy file from one location to other
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, targetFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'd think this is not CPU, but I/O bound operation. This will never utilize 100% CPU, especially with that horsepower... By the way, why do you use `ImageIO` for this? As you don't do any processing, just File IO, you could use generic (and quicker) methods for copzing the files...

Comment: Indeed, I haven't considered that. The images come from an external HD using some USB 2.0... Not the quickest way to convert them probably... Thanks a lot! I will have a look at the File IO.

Comment: Well, USB 2.0 isn't the fastest thing. I think you don't need this to be multithreaded, I'd either just wait until it finishes, or find a way to use the disk as a SATA device directly... That might have a tremendous effect on the speed

Comment: Thanks, usually I would run it on my SSD, but because its around 1 TB of images SSD is not really an option. Because I'm running that on my Laptop, I will probably need to find me a computer with a bigger internal HD... Or I just wait until it finishes... But I'm glad it's not ONLY because of my programming style because this was now annoying me for the last 3 hours ;)

Comment: With USB2.0, you can expect 1/2 day of reading/writing time, no matter the CPU :)

Comment: Yes, it's really slow. And it's a real shame because both my external drives are USB 3.0, but my Laptop is too old so it doesn't have an USB 3.0 port... So waiting or finding another computer it is...;)

Comment: Maybe try out the new file io in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that the bottleneck here definitly is the I/O to the disk.
You might need the same time renaming your files without an ExecutorService.

In other words: Writing the changes (renaming the files) to the disk consumes more time than used by your CPU.

You cannot multithread such an action.

Just measure the time needed in a serial (non-multithreaded) version of your code and compare it to the the time needed with your multithreaded code. It will be more or less the same.